# Intellij 13 on Mac snow leopard not compiling

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I have recently installed java 1.7.0_45 and intellij 13 on snow leopard (10.6.8)

I've been able to compile classes and run java programs from the command line using java 1.7.

Intellij is linked to the java 1.7.0_45 install and code completion and other source functionality is working fine, but when i try to make the project i get the following:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
  2014-01-16 15:16:25.169 java[1467:903] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x10871b390 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
  2014-01-16 15:16:25.171 java[1467:903] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x10871b390 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

Comment: Snow Leopard is ancient, it's probably an issue of the ObjC runtime being outdated, and Oracle doesn't bother to test compatibility that well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the same problem and I think it is due to the incompatibility of JDK7 with Snow Leopard.

Although it is possible to install JDK7 on to 10.6 by [getting the OS to misreport the version](http://jksha.blogspot.se/2013/09/java-7-and-snow-leopard-osx-106.html) so that the installer just gets on with it, that workaround has a limited lifespan and this may be it.

Attempting to install JDK 1.7.0_45 and _51 both give the same result for both Intellij 12 and 13 so it looks like this is a dead end for Java on Snow Leopard.

It may be worth the 5Gb download to upgrade to Mavericks since after I did this it all worked. You can avoid Intellij asking for JDK6 on startup by [following these instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956).